# Changing ODK 3.11 nodeip

Tags: openshift, okd

I've got a dev cluster built with virtualbox, vagrant and the dockered ansible intsaller of openshift.
So far I haven't found out how can I force the installer to use the eth1 address as the nodeip of the nodes. It is always 10.0.2.15.
So far I've tried `route add 8.8.8.8 gw 192.168.33.1` so that ansible identifies the eth1 subnet as default. Also tried setting `openshift_ip` on the nodes (in conjunction with `openshift_public_ip`).
No success. I also noticed that the variable `openshift_set_node_ip` got deprecated which served this specific purpose.
So how can I change the node ip during installation? (Or even afterwards... oc edit node doesn't work either, it flips back even though the changes are saved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should the node hostnames be resolved by specific IP address you'd like to configure using DNS. And the NIC interface which is allocated each node IP should be configured as only one default gateway.

Then you can install with the following inventory variables.
You should defined each node group for each node host separately.
Refer [Node Group Definition](https://docs.okd.io/3.11/install/configuring_inventory_file.html#configuring-inventory-node-group-definitions) for node group details.

e.g.> I insert the indentation to `openshift_node_groups` for readability, but you should configure as one line.

```
openshift_node_groups=[
                       {'name': 'node-config-master1', 
                        'labels': ['node-role.kubernetes.io/master=true'], 
                        'edits': [{ 'key': 'nodeIP','value': '1.1.1.1'}]}, 
                       {'name': 'node-config-masterX'
                       ...                                              
                       },
                       {'name': 'node-config-infra1', 
                        'labels': ['node-role.kubernetes.io/infra=true'], 
                        'edits': [{ 'key': 'nodeIP','value': '2.2.2.2'}]},
                       {'name': 'node-config-infraX'
                       ...
                       },
                       {'name': 'node-config-compute1', 
                        'labels': ['node-role.kubernetes.io/compute=true'], 
                        'edits': [{ 'key': 'nodeIP','value': '3.3.3.3'}]},
                       {'name': 'node-config-computeX'
                       ...
                       }
                       ]

[nodes]
master1.example.com openshift_node_group_name='node-config-master1'
...
masterX.example.com openshift_node_group_name='node-config-masterX'
infra1.example.com  openshift_node_group_name='node-config-infra1'
...
infraX.example.com  openshift_node_group_name='node-config-infraX'
compute1.example.com  openshift_node_group_name='node-config-compute1'
...
computeX.example.com  openshift_node_group_name='node-config-computeX'
```